# GFCI turns off with bath light

Tags: gfci

I have a GFCI outlet that has green light when the bathroom light is on and a red light when the bathroom light is turned off. The GFCI works perfectly and does not trip when the light is on. When the bathroom light is off no power flows and the red LED comes on.

Comment: What make and model is the GFCI receptacle?

Comment: Remove the wires from the LOAD terminals of the GFCI.  (This may break the light, if so, that's ok for this test).  Does the GFCI operate normally or does it lose power?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the wiring has gotten mixed up.  That receptacle is now being switched along with the bathroom light. The receptacle needs full time power ahead of this switch. However, this receptacle should not even be on the same circuit as these lights.  The receptacle should be on a 20-Amp circuit, 12-guage wire.  Bathroom lighting is usually on a 15-Amp circuit, 14-guage wire. Hair blow dryers, use in bath rooms require too much power for a 15-Amp circuit.  Hope this helps some. P.

Comment: There is no reason why the lights cannot run off of the same 20A circuit, nor no reason why it cannot be ran off the load side of the GFCI, but clearly, the switch should not be on the line side of the GFCI

Comment: I'm ok with not GFCI-protecting luminaires, which are not incandescent.  With incandescent you can break a bulb and touch a filament, but CFLs the filaments will be isolated, and LEDs are not removable/touchable, and low voltage in any case.